# Error in Google Analytics AJAX Function On JSON Responce

Tags: javascript, html, regex, google-analytics

I'm creating a Google Analytics Dashboard. In there is an AJAX function as below. This AJAX function is used to pass the query string to the JSON webservice.

```
function setJsonSer() {
 $.ajax({
    url: "/APIWebService.asmx/AnalyticsDataShowWithPost",
    type: 'POST',

    data:{Email:'email@website.com',Password:'password',URL:getVaria()},

    success: function (data) {
        alert("success alert "+'sucess');

        var sTitle = $(data).find('string').text();
        alert("sTitle Alert "+ sTitle);

        alert(data);
    },

    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('error in simple method');
        alert(textStatus);
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});

 $.ajax({
    url: "/APIWebService.asmx/GetMessage",
    type: 'POST',

    data:{Email:'email@website.com',Password:'password',URL:getVaria()},

    success: function (data) {
        //alert('sucess - getMessage');

        var sTitle = $(data).find('string').text();
        //alert(sTitle);

        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('error in simple method');
        //alert(textStatus);
        //alert(errorThrown);
      }
   });

 }
```

This getVaria() function is an another external JavaScript file & the above code snipet is in the Google Analytics Dashboards UI. I have properly linked both files. So no errors in there.

In the setJsonSer() function I have alert the sTitle and I got the output with an error. The error code is 400.

***Error***

{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"invalidParameter","message":"Invalid value ' 20140724 '. Values must match the following regular expression: '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}|today|yesterday|[0-9]+(daysAgo)'","locationType":"parameter","location":"end-date"},{"domain":"global","reason":"invalidParameter","message":"Invalid value ' 20140701 '. Values must match the following regular expression: '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}|today|yesterday|[0-9]+(daysAgo)'","locationType":"parameter","location":"start-date"}],"code":400,"message":"Invalid value ' 20140724 '. Values must match the following regular expression: '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}|today|yesterday|[0-9]+(daysAgo)'"}}

I have change the date format & removed "-" and "/". But the error is still triggering. So what are you thinking about this matter?

***Update***

**Function to format the date.**
    $(function() {

```
      //$("#to_date").datepicker({  maxDate: new Date()});
      //$("#from_date").datepicker({  maxDate: new Date()});

      $("#to_date, #from_date").datepicker({maxDate: new Date(),dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});

              $("div.ui-datepicker").css( { "font-size": "10px" } );        

  });
```

**The HTML Form**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    From Date : <input type="text" id="from_date" />
    To Date : <input type="text" id="to_date" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit_button" onClick="setJsonSer();  return false" />
    </form>
```

This setJsonVar() is being explained in the above.

Thanks & regards,
Chiranthaka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clearly explained in error that

```
Values must match the following regular expression: '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}|today|yesterday|[0-9]+(daysAgo)
```

so you are allowed to use different words like today , yesterday or date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

So you should keep same format while passing date. your format is `yyyymmdd`.   You need to change it according to requirement.

Comment: I have entered the date with yyyy-mm-dd format but in the textbox it shows as 20102010-07-01 & 20142014-07-24. If I change it to yy-mm-dd it shows perfectly as 2014-07-01 & 2014-07-24. However both these did not solve the error. So how can I solve the matter?

Comment: Can you add code related to date handling, means textbox and etc